# laravel helper asset function calling UrlGenerator::asset function...connecting the dots

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, frameworks

I am trying to understand how the helper function asset() is calling the function UrlGenerator::asset() in laravel.

I understand that the helper is called through the bootstrapping process but how does this

`if ( ! function_exists('asset'))
{
    /**
     * Generate an asset path for the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return string
     */
    function asset($path, $secure = null)
    {
        return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
    }
}`

make the call to the UrlGenerator class when it isn't even mentioned in the referring function?

Comment: **return app('url')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Laravel casses instances are stored inside app, and then there are Facades that statically call the real instances.

Some reading in the docs

- http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle
- http://laravel.com/docs/facades
- http://laravel.com/docs/ioc

or at other sources

- http://eddmann.com/posts/how-static-facades-and-ioc-are-used-in-laravel/

For the assets use the `URL::asset()` method or its *alias* `asset()`. More on

- http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls
- http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/